# Real-Tine transcription

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I am playing with the real-time conversation

and I get this error

IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

could somebody help me, please

```
 public static async Task TranscribeConversationsAsync(string voiceSignatureStringUser1, string voiceSignatureStringUser2)
{
    var filepath = "Tech.wav";

    var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(VoiceGenerator.subscriptionKey, VoiceGenerator.region);
    config.SetProperty("ConversationTranscriptionInRoomAndOnline", "true");

    // en-us by default. Adding this code to specify other languages, like zh-cn.
    // config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "zh-cn";
    var stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(filepath))
    {
        var meetingID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        using (var conversation = await Conversation.CreateConversationAsync(config, meetingID))
        {
            // create a conversation transcriber using audio stream input
            using (var conversationTranscriber = new ConversationTranscriber(audioInput))
            {
                conversationTranscriber.Transcribing += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"TRANSCRIBING: Text={e.Result.Text} SpeakerId={e.Result.UserId}");
                };

                conversationTranscriber.Transcribed += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"TRANSCRIBED: Text={e.Result.Text} SpeakerId={e.Result.UserId}");
                    }
                    else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
                    }
                };

                conversationTranscriber.Canceled += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={e.Reason}");

                    if (e.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={e.ErrorCode}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={e.ErrorDetails}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you set the speech resource key and region values?");
                        stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                    }
                };

                conversationTranscriber.SessionStarted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nSession started event. SessionId={e.SessionId}");
                };

                conversationTranscriber.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nSession stopped event. SessionId={e.SessionId}");
                    Console.WriteLine("\nStop recognition.");
                    stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                };

                // Add participants to the conversation.
                var speaker1 = Participant.From("User1", "en-US", voiceSignatureStringUser1);
                var speaker2 = Participant.From("User2", "en-US", voiceSignatureStringUser2);
                await conversation.AddParticipantAsync(speaker1);
                await conversation.AddParticipantAsync(speaker2);

                // Join to the conversation and start transcribing
                await conversationTranscriber.JoinConversationAsync(conversation);
                await conversationTranscriber.StartTranscribingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                // waits for completion, then stop transcription
                Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });
                await conversationTranscriber.StopTranscribingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
```

It appears that something is blocking my connection, but why? I Searched of google, but I only find reference for ASP, not for console apps

Comment: Could be any number of network issues but could be an issue with setting up a secure connection.

Comment: I came here hoping this question was going to be about forks :(